# How to make a socket server that listens for client connections and opens a socket once an Endpoint is called in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration, serversocket

I have an application that opens a "HttpURLConnection" to a printer. The printer is listening for socket connection and makes a connection when a new TCP socket connection is opened on the Application side (In this case through a new "HttpURLConnection"). Now, I want to mock this printer.

In the Application an Http call is made to the printer server and a socket connection is established between the Application and the server. How do I mock this printer as a spring boot application.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to take a look into Spring Test Framework and especially its part about a Web: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-client

I would really investigate a possibility to interact via a `RestTemplate` instead of direct `HttpURLConnection` and then use that `MockRestServiceServer` for mocking requests and responses.

Another way is to use a `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` and implement controller with appropriate mappings and possible return results. This way you would be able to use the mentioned `HttpURLConnection` to connect to randomly allocated port for HTTP server and perform requests as in production.